# Bluetooth Receiver response time

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver

I have following receiver (very simple):

```
bluetoothReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED)) {
            stopMusic();
        }
    }
};

ctx.registerReceiver(bluetoothReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED));
```

Permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```

What I want to do, is to stop music when BT headphones disconnect. It works, however the response time is not good - the music continues for about a second from the device, until the event is detected by receiver. I checked Youtube app and there this scenario works almost immediately, without playing any music from the devices' speakers. Any idea how to achieve the broadcast receiver to detect the `ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED` immediately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: Try to setup a higher priority for the IntentFilter you are creating

```
ItentFilter intentFilter= new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED); 
intentFilter.setPriority(999) /// highest possible priority value 
ctx.registerReceiver(bluetoothReceiver, intentFilter);
```

Filters with a higher-priority should be executed before the application code

[See the android documentation for further information.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html#SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY)

Option 2: If the broadcast receiver still doesn´t detect the ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED immediately and the device is still playing music for a short time, you could also try to setup an intentfilter that listens if the audio outputs are changing(AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY). Here you could stop the device from playing music as well.

[Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY)

Comment: AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY did the trick. And now it covers not only BT headphones, but all audio changes. Thanks!